# How do I do mysql join statement on multiple table hierarchy levels?

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose I have the following table house:

```
House:
id
name
cityID
```

Where cityID refers to the id field of table city

```
City:
id
name
stateID
```

where stateID refers to the id field of table state

```
State:
id
name
countryID
```

where countryID refers to the id field of the table country:

```
Country:
id
name
```

How do I do mysql join statements so that I can obtain houses within a specific country using this multiple level location reference hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use joins or nested queries:

```
Select House.* from ((House join City on House.CityID = City.id)
                          join State on City.StateID = State.id)
                          join Country on State.CountryID = Country.id
               where Country.name = 'Australia'
```

or

```
Select * from House where CityID in (
    Select id from City where StateID in (
        Select id from State where CountryID in (
            Select id from Country where name = 'Australia'
        )
    )
)
```